# Sorting WordPress woocommerce products in columns for sitemap php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This is the code i have at the moment i am trying to display the content in colums as i get one long list with this method.

I have seached google and found how to do this with posts but cant seem to get it to work with this

```
<div class="span4">
          <div class="myclass">
            <h3>
              <?php _e('Products','mytheme'); ?>
              <i class=" icon-double-angle-down"></i></h3>
            <div class="full-line"></div>
          </div>
          <ul class="sitemap-ul">
            <?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'meta_query' => array( array('key' => '_visibility','value' => array('catalog', 'visible'))) );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
              <?php the_title(); ?>
              </a></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

The html output for   Ohgodwhy answer

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">product</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><a href="#">product</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">product</a></td>
     <td><a href="#">product</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

its now rendering like this

| product |
| product |
| product || product |

Comment: If you don't pass in the `meta_query` does this work fine? if not, there are larger issues at play

Comment: This gives me the products in a long list but am needing it in columns maybe 30 products in each one. not to sure what you mean by "If you don't pass in the meta_query does this work fine?" i am very new to this and adapted this code for the web

Comment: So what you're saying is you're getting the data but the output in the browser is not the way that you want it, yeah?

Comment: yep :) its rendering as one long list thats making the page extremly long, this is why i need it columns

Comment: How many columns? What do you want to split it on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From clarification in the comments it sounds like you just need to restructure your HTML output for the browser.

```
<table class="sitemap-ul">
    <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'meta_query' => array( array('key' => '_visibility','value' => array('catalog', 'visible'))) );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    $i = 0;?>
    <tr>

    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        if($i % 3) echo '</tr><tr>';?>
        <td>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </td>

   <?php $i++; endwhile;?>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The result of the above will generate a table and every 3rd item it will end the row and then create a new row, appending 3 more products to it.

Comment: this is still rendering as a list downwards :/ please see my question for the html output